# What is the difference: "doesn't come" vs "won't come"

Tags: future-tense

I was doing an exercise and came across this:

> If the teacher ... we ... the exam(not come, not have).

So my guess would be one of the followings:

> If the teacher doesn't come we won't have the exam.
>
> If the teacher won't come we won't have the exam.

Could you please explain what should be in places of dots and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the rule is that the future (*will*, *won't*) can't be used in an IF clause.

IF clauses use the present tense to discuss the condition under which future events will or won't happen.  So "If the teacher **doesn't** come, we **won't** have the exam" is the correct form.

(Sometimes "will"/"won't" is permitted if the meaning is "is/isn't willing to".  If "the teacher won't come" was intended to mean "the teacher refuses to come" then "If the teacher won't come" would be acceptable wording.)

From the [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-1) website:

> We use the first conditional when we talk about real and possible situations.
>
> - I’**ll** go shopping on the way home **if** I **have** time.
> - **If** it’**s** a nice day tomorrow, we’**ll** go to the beach.
> - **If** Arsenal **win**, they’**ll** be top of the league.
>
> In first conditional sentences, the structure is usually **if** + *present simple* and **will** + *infinitive*. It’s not important which clause comes first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your intent:

> 1. State the fact that is always true. Then you use present tense in both if clause and main clause. *If the teacher doesn't come, we don't have an exam.*
> 2. You want to describe one possible outcome, when the situation is real. You use present tense in the if clause and future tense in the main clause. *If the teacher doesn't come, we won't have an exam.*

There are other conditional situations that need different grammar, but future tense is not used in the if clause. Take a look [here.](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/)